# protractor - Avoiding StaleElementReferenceError in a generic manner

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am writing end to end tests using protractor for a GWT application.

It is a fairly large application and the tests need to use nested locators.

Protractor has these **ElementFinder** and **ElementArrayFinder** wrapper classes over the Selenium WebElement which are really useful. One of the advantages I see is that the Selenium WebElement is located only when there is a call to the WebElement **actions**(click(), sendKeys() etc.).

This approach avoids the **StaleElementReferenceError** in many cases.

However there are still cases where we are getting **StaleElementReferenceErrors**. Invoking actions In a hierarchy of ElementFinders/ElementArrayFinders is one such case.
  E.g.

```
var openCmd: protractor.ElementFinder
$('.main_panel').$('.items').$('.celllist').filter(function(elem, index) {
    return elem.$('.cellTitle').getText().then(function(text) {
        return text === 'Ranjith';
    });
}).first().$(".commandPanel a[title='Open']");

openCmd.click();
```

> Here, it is locating a cellist in  a section of the page, and then
>   finding a cell with title 'Ranjith' and then locating the
>   command(anchor) with title 'Open' inside that cell.

When click() is called on the openCmd, it would traverse the hierarchy of locators(from .main_panel to the command) to locate the command WebElement and will execute click() on the same. Now, If a DOM refresh happened during this traversal or the action(click()), it would throw StaleElementReferenceErrors.

I have seen posts where there were suggestions to use a retry approach:

- https://github.com/juliemr/webdriverjs-retry
- https://github.com/mekdev/mocha-selenium-pageobject/blob/master/src/pageobjects/BasePage.js

Both of these do not solve the problem, I still get StaleElementReferenceErrors.

Also, I do not want all my test developers to write wrappers or call extra methods from their page objects. I want to implement this retry in the framework code so that it is taken care of in the background smoothly and the test developers don't have to worry about the same as they will be using the  protractor ElementFinder and ElementArrayFinder objects normally.

I am working on a solution to put a retry recursion by having my own implementation of **protractor.ElementArrayFinder.prototype.applyAction_()** method to solve this at the framework level.

Basically to retry n number of times on StaleElementReferenceErrors.

Two questions:

- Is there an implementation that works consistently for doing the
  retry on StaleElementReferenceErrors?
- Why such a retry approach is not given as part of the angular
  ElementArrayFinder implementation itself?

Thanks in Advance,

Ranjith

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you, and it's really annoying. The worst is that, it makes test unstable. Have you managed to figure out a better solution than wrapping?